# Why don't some subtitles match with the movie?

Tags: video, subtitles

During watching some movies, it happens that we have to download the subtitle files(srts) from different sites.

In a single site, we can find dozens of English srts for a single movie. But the srts are different in some way and the main difference which I found is the timing of inappropriate srts don't match with the timing of the movie i.e. either the srt leads or lags when the movie is being played.

So what are the factors should we take into account during downloading a proper subtitle of a proper file of a movie? Why is there a mismatch between subtitle timings across different subtitle files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what are the factors should we take into account during downloading
>   a proper subtitle of a proper file of a movie? Why is there a mismatch
>   between subtitle timings across different subtitle files?

There are MANY reasons behind this.

Some of which are:

- Movies can run at different framerates, thus different amounts of time between dialogs
- A movie may not always start from the exact same frame as a copy of the movie from a different source, leading to a desync of the subtitles and voice
- Scenes in a movie may be deleted for some markets. This will lead to subtitles made for a version from a different market desynchronized. Such censored movies are not always clearly marked as different from the original

Answer (score 2):

First, the video you download can be edited. Those stupid advertisements can be cut out, or "Downloaded from ***" added. 
Next, after many container conversions (HD->mkv->streaming->mkv again)the alignment of tracks can shift due to bugs in software. 
Finally, some older subtitles where keyed not by time, but by frame number, and modern codecs have variable frame rate.

I use VLC player on my PC, and it allows me to adjust timing of all tracks.